# "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function()" occurs while testing with phpunit

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have some tests for my phpproject. My tests:

```
class myTests extends PHPunit_Framework_Testcase{
    public function testValidateInventoryNumber(){
        include('includes/functions.php');
        $con = connectToDatabase();

        $resultTest1 = validateInventoryNumber("001234", $con);
        $this->assertEquals("001234", $resultTest1['data']);
    }

    public function testValidateLabel(){
        include('includes/functions.php');

        $resultTest1 = validateLabel("Sample Label.");
        $this->assertEquals("Sample Label.", $resultTest1['data']);
    }
}
```

The functions `validateInventoryNumber()` and `validateLabel()` are declared in `includes/functions.php`, so I need to include this file in both tests, am I right?

If I want to run the testfile, i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connectToDatabase() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\includes\functions.php:4) in C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\includes\functions.php on line 10
```

I think it has something to do with the includes at the start of the tests, because if I comment out one of the tests, it works properly. Any idea how it can be fixed?

Comment: Your include() calls. Make it include_once()

Comment: Simple as that... Thank you so much, it works now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@Karlo Kokkak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829499/karlo-kokkak)who mentioned the solution in the comments. Instead of `include('includes/functions.php');`, use `include_once('includes/functions.php');`.